# Optimizing Entity Framework queries for import

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

As I have import data from database with context `MICSYDBCONTEXT` to database with `BRIA_REALDBCONTEXT`.

As there are 280'000 records in the `MICSYDBCONTEXT` database I see that it takes 5 hours to import just 10000 records so I desperately need of some kind of optimization of my queries. I'm using Entity Framework 6 and as a junior developer I would appreciate any help.

```
using (var context = new MICSYDBContext())
{
    var Doc = context.DOCUMENTS.OrderBy(x => x.ID).Take(100);

    try
    {
        using (var context2 = new BRIA_REALDBCONTEXT())
        {
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            foreach (var item in Doc)
            {
              var DOC = new DLV_DOC();
              DOC.FOLDID = item.ID;
              DOC.FOBJECT = 1;
              DOC.FIO = 40;              
              DOC.FID = newId;
              DOC.FACTIVE = "Y";
              DOC.FCODEWRT = 85;
              DOC.FDOC_COUNT_ORIGINAL = 'N';
              DOC.FUSERINSERT = 85;
              DOC.FMODULE = 1;
              DOC.FSERVICE_TYPE = 1;

              var micsysserviceName = context.DEFDOCTYPE.Where(x => x.ID == item.DOCTYPE).FirstOrDefault();

              if (micsysserviceName != null)
              {
                var service = context2.DLV_SSERVICE.Where(x => x.FNAME == micsysserviceName.NAME && x.FSERVICE_TYPE == 1).FirstOrDefault();

                if (service != null)
                {
                  DOC.FSERVICE = service.FID;
                }
              }
              else
              {
                DOC.FSERVICE = 1;
              }

              var personcorespondent = context2.UCM_PERSON.Where(x => x.FOLD_ID == item.DOCKORID.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();

              if (personcorespondent != null)
              {
                DOC.FPERSON = personcorespondent.FID;
              }
              else
              { 
                  DOC.FPERSON = 142; 
              }

              DOC.FDATEDOC = item.DATA;

              foreach (var docsteps in context.DOCMOVE.Where(x => x.DOCID == item.ID).OrderBy(x => x.DATA))
              {//СТъпка
                DLV_DOC_STEP DLVSTEP = new DLV_DOC_STEP();
                DLVSTEP.FDOC = DOC.FID;
                DLVSTEP.FOBJECT = 1;
                DLVSTEP.FCODEWRT = 85;


                var whofirst = context2.UCM_PERSON.Where(x => x.FOLD_ID == docsteps.WHOFIRST.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
                if (whofirst != null)
                {
                  DLVSTEP.FPERSON = whofirst.FID;
                }
                var whonext = context2.UCM_PERSON.Where(x => x.FOLD_ID == docsteps.WHONEXT.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
                if (whonext != null)
                {
                  DLVSTEP.FTOPERSON = whonext.FID;
                }

                context2.DLV_DOC_STEP.Add(DLVSTEP);
              }

              context2.DLV_DOC.Add(DOC);
              i++;
              Console.WriteLine("Added " +i + "DOC");
            }
            context2.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("End of docs");
            Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.Hours);
          }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          string s = ex.Message;
          Console.WriteLine("Problem with record");
          Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
          Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
          Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
        }
      }
```

Comment: You want to order 280000 records. That's gonna take a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is very common,

We can split it into three category:

- Add vs AddRange Performance
- Read & database round-trip
- Write & database round-trip

**Add vs AddRange Performance**

The Add method will try to detect change every time you add a new record while the AddRange only does it once. Detecting changes every time can take several minutes.

This issue is very easy to fix, simply create two lists, add entity to this list instead and use AddRange with the list at the end.

```
var DLV_DOC_STEPS = new List<DLV_DOC_STEP>();
var DLV_DOCS = new List<DLV_DOC>();

foreach(...)
{
    foreach(...)
    {
        DLV_DOC_STEPS.Add(DLVSTEP);
    }

    DLV_DOCS.Add(DOC);
}

context2.DLV_DOC_STEP.AddRange(DLV_DOC_STEPS);
context2.DLV_DOC.AddRange(DLV_DOC);
context2.SaveChanges
```

An alternative solution is disabling AutoDetectChange at the start && re-enabling it before the SaveChanges. I recommend the first solution but both work.

```
ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
foreach(var item in Doc)
{
    // ...code...
}

ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

**Read & Database round-trip**

The application is performing way too many database round-trips

You make a query in the following entities multiple times:

- DEFDOCTYPE
- DLV_SSERVICE
- UCM_PERSON
- DOCMOVE

You perform millions of database round-trips which is insane, so your application is of course very slow!

*Solution?*

- Try to load all data first and use a dictionary instead to get the entity from memory (if the table doesn't contain too many records).

Example:

```
var defDoctTypeDict = context.DEFDOCTYPE.AsNoTracking().ToList().ToDictionary(x => x.ID);

foreach(var item in Doc)
{
    DEFDOCTYPE micsysserviceName;

    defDoctTypeDict.TryGetValue(item.DOCTYPE, out micsysserviceName);
    if(micsysserviceName != null)
    {
        // ...code...
    }

    // ...code...
}
```

- Try to load data in batch by creating a list and using List.Contains instead
  You can read someone having a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38355262/5619143
- Use AsNoTracking if you don't need to track the entity

**Write & Database round-trip**

Everytime you save a record, you perform a database round-trip.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library allows to perform:

- BulkSaveChanges
- BulkInsert
- BulkUpdate
- BulkDelete
- BulkMerge

You can either call BulkSaveChanges at the end of the batch or create a list to insert and use directly BulkInsert instead for even more performance.

BulkSaveChanges Solution (Way faster than SaveChanges)

```
context2.DLV_DOC_STEP.AddRange(DLV_DOC_STEPS);
context2.DLV_DOC.AddRange(DLV_DOC);
context2.BulkSaveChanges
```

BulkInsert Solution (Fastest than BulkSaveChanges but do not save related entities)

```
context2.BulkInsert(DLV_DOC_STEPS);
context2.BulkInsert(DLV_DOC);
```